# Quit all instances of `gnome-terminal` via a command

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

This is half "this'd be useful for me" and half "hobby project" - I was wondering if it's possible to send a command via a `gnome-terminal` that will quit all instances of a program without using `killall`.

Essentially I'd like to write a script, which I will put in my `$PATH`, that will try and exit all open terminal windows as if the close button had been clicked on each, rather than killing. The reason being that I have a terrible habit of opening many terminal windows at once and it's a hassle to go through each of them and quit all of them individually. Simply typing `exeunt` (because let's face it, there's no better name for a command to "exit all") and having them all quit would be far better for me. However, I don't want to accidentally close any programs that are still running from within a terminal - I still want to see any "There is still a process running in this terminal" prompts, so the command `killall gnome-terminal` would be out of the question.

The ideal I suppose would be a command-line / bash equivalent of rightclicking on the Dash icon and pressing "quit". Possibly a slightly unorthodox request, but I'd be interested to know if it's somehow possible.

Answer (score 2):

Despite it's name, `killall` (and `kill`) sends `SIGTERM` signal to all the process with the same name, also you can personalize the signal sent with the `-s` switch. So, instead using `killall gnome-terminal` you can use `killall -s {signal} gnome-terminal`.

I haven't find out what signal can be interpreted as *click at the close button*, but my guess is, that it's a GUI hook that trigger such behavior. In gnome2 there was a "Close all" option in the task list, but in gnome3 seems such option it's lost.

### After a lengthy discussion over U&L

With the help of [slm](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/59955/slm) who [gave me the idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85210/41104), you can simulate the <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> key combination on several instances of gnome-terminal using `xdotool search --name terminal key --window %@ alt+F4`. You must be sure you have installed `xdotool` using:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

But, lets me explain in detail:

`search` do a search of all window with a determinated characteristics. `--name` switch will look for windows with the content on the title bar. `key` tells `xdotool` that we are going to use keyboard commands. `--window` tells to use a determinated ID for the `key` command, if not set it will use `%1` from the stack. `%@` means to use all the stack of ID's. `alt+F4` tells the key combination to send.

More information:

[www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml)

Comment: killall (and kill) only send an actual KILL signal when you explicitly tell it to do so, the default signal is TERM(inate). You can look up all the signals in `man 7 signal`.

Comment: Interesting. Is there a signal that I can send that'd be interpreted as an alt-f4 or a "close", though? Otherwise the only way I can think of along these lines would be to delve into the gnome terminal source and put in a handler for SIGUSR1 / 2 to tell it to close cleanly, by the looks of that list.

Comment: Sorry, been away for a while. Seems like a very nice solution, but doesn't quite seem to work as expected (by the look of things it sends an alt-f4 signal for each open terminal window, but doesn't switch between them in between - so what happens is the "Close this window?" prompt flashes on and off for a little bit for the terminal window in which the command is run (as `xdotool` counts as a running program while the command is still running)

Comment: @JezW Well, you actually asked how to "Quit all instances of `gnome-terminal` via a command" which this answer do at the perfection. If you want to do something more elaborate, ask another question or read the manual ;).

Comment: It doesn't, though. When I type it, it brings up a "close this window?" prompt for the active terminal window (and even then only if there are an odd number of terminals open - if it's an even number the prompt flickers on and off and disappears) - it doesn't have any effect on any of the other open windows...

Comment: Did you noticed that if your "terminals" don't have the name "terminal" in the title it wouldn't work. Ex. if your terminals has "JezW@pc" in the title, you should run `xdotool search --name JezW key --window %@ alt+F4` to close them all. If some application changes this, then you should use `--class` or `--classname` accordingly. I only offered an example that you should modify to fit your requirements. Another example, for me `xdotool search --name "gedit|terminal|office" key --window %@ alt+F4` will close any window that has gedit, terminal or office in their name.

Comment: @JezW check your selectors, since something must be missing.

Comment: Putting my username instead of the word "terminal" does exactly the same thing - it seems to (in effect) count how many terminal windows are open, and then presses alt+f4 that many times (i.e. with 3 open, the "Close this terminal?" prompt for the active terminal appears, disappears and then reappears)

Comment: Could you post what `xdotool search --name JezW` outputs. In my case I fired 10 terminals, then used `bash` to pin them, and the behavior you describe doesn't happen. Try adding `--sync` to the command. Also,`xdotool getactivewindow` to check the active number and compare it to your list. If you want you can [chat] with me, to don't make this comments too extended.